# Choose from dropdown list in Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I need to select an option form a dropdown list.
I tried many ways to click on the dropdown then select the option I need, the click on the dropdown success but it fails in selecting the choice.

Here are the lines of code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//* [@id="arid_WIN_3_1000000163"]'))).click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".MenuEntryNameHover").click()
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[contains(text(), "4-Minor/Localized")]').click()
```

This is the inspected HTML element:

```
<div class="selection" style="top:0px; left:124px; width:212px; height:21px;" arselmenu="[{ci:1000,v:&quot;1-Extensive/Widespread&quot;},{ci:2000,v:&quot;2-Significant/Large&quot;},{ci:3000,v:&quot;3-Moderate/Limited&quot;},{ci:4000,v:&quot;4-Minor/Localized&quot;}]">
<input id="arid_WIN_3_1000000163" type="text" class="text " readonly="" style="top:0px; left:0px; width:191px; height:21px;" title="4-Minor/Localized">
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d selectionbtn" style="top:0px; left:191px; width:21px; height:21px;">
<img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" alt="">
</a>
</div>
```

This is the screenshot

[image: Dropdown List Image]

Comment: How has the dropdown been achieved? By html element `<select><option></option></select>` method or with javascript?

Comment: Thanks Suramuthu,
I edited the question with HTML Lines, Can you read it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Select class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) which will allow you to select an option by the visible text or by its value.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# target select control
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("...."))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text("4-Minor/Localized")

# select by value 
select.select_by_value("4")
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, But it didn't work. I updated the question with HTML Lines to be more clarified.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time


dr = webdriver.Chrome()

#change the url
url = '<the_url_to_be_scrapped>'

dr.get(url)
drop=Select(dr.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"selection")

#change the visible text according to your requirement
drop.select_by_visible_text("4-Minor/Localized")

time.sleep(4)
driver.close()
```